# The boundary of an open subset of $[0,1]$ containing all rationals in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $A\subset [0,1]$ is the union of open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such that each rational number of $(0,1)$ is contained in some $(a_i,b_i)$, prove that the boundary (frontier) of $A$ is $[0,1]-A$.

I don't know what to do in this exercise.

Comment: Good answers have already been provided, but let me point out the interesting fact that for any $\epsilon > 0$ one can choose intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ such that $A := \bigcup (a_i, b_i) \supset \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1)$ has measure $\mu(A) < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rationals in $(0,1)$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Hence the closure of $A$ is $[0,1]$. Since $A$ is the union of open intervals, $A$ itself is an open set. Therefore the interior of $A$ is $A$ itself. By definition, the boundary of $A$ is the set theoretic difference of the closure of $A$ and the interior of $A$. Thus the boundary in our case is $[0,1] - A$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the density of rationals to show that $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Then, since $A$ is open, the boundary must be $[0,1] \setminus A$